# gitlab repositories are not showing in my navigator

Tags: gitlab-ce, kubernetes-pvc

I deployed successfully my gitlab with kubernetes via pods and services. but when I open navigator to log in my account, my created repositories does not appear. I set up a pv and pvc to save my repositories. when I am creating a project with same name, it show me an error. That means that my project are stocked but not showing in my user interface.

This is my source code:

[image]

This is how i defined one of my PVC:

[image]

Comment: have you exec'd into your container to see if there are any log messages?

Comment: there are no logs , it's just not showing my repositories in the UI but showing all my /data files in my node